# Spring Boot REST API application level authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, authorization

Currently building a Spring boot based REST API application (sample centralised school management system). There are various DB entities which are given CRUD access via the APIs, like **Account**, **School**, any sub-entity of school like **teacher,student** etc.

Suppose we have many APIs like

```
GET /api/getschooldetails?account_id=1&school_id=1
GET /api/getteacherlist?account_id=3&school_id=2
GET /api/getstudentdetails?account_id=3&school_id=2&student_id=1
```

Similarly POST with JSON request body

```
POST /api/addteacher
request : {"account_id":3,"school_id":2,"teachername":"XYZ"}
and 
POST /api/updatestudentname
request : {"account_id":3,"school_id":2,"student_id":4,"name":"ABC"}
```

How to add authorisation at API level for the request params/JSON fields so that those users who have authenticated as `school_id=2` should get access error if they try to modify API call `/api/getteacherlist?account_id=3&school_id=2` to `/api/getteacherlist?account_id=3&school_id=3` and get `school_id=3` details.

Thinking of adding `@Before` AOP point for each Controller class to parse query param/JSON and do DB based userid validation i.e. if the userid logged in (via Spring Security Authentication) has access to the account_id and school_id mentioned in the request as they are part of every request in order to avoid code duplication or adding the same check in every DAO class before performing the actual CRUD operation. Please guide if there is any other way using Spring.

Comment: or you could just use method security, in combination with the role based security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-method and not invent custom security which is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not invent custom security. Use for example Keycloak and Spring Security https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak